# THREE.JS - how to draw Halo (external outline) to circular sector

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to draw halo (external black outline) to some shapes in three.js. while i did it easily with rectangle and circle, i have a lot of trouble with circular sector (not-full circle).

So far, this is the best i have got:

[image]

As you can see, it is not perfect (the halo is 'on' the mesh on the circle's
 center)

This is the code:

```
var radius = 50
var segments = 32;
var thetaStart = 0;                   
var thetaLength = 0.5 * Math.PI; 

var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments, thetaStart, thetaLength);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
var circle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

/* create halo */
var unit =  1 / radius; 
var biggerGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius + 2, segments, thetaStart - 2*unit, thetaLength + 4*unit); 
var haloGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(biggerGeometry);    
var haloMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 }); //black halo    
var halo = new THREE.LineSegments(haloGeometry, haloMaterial);
circle.add(halo);
```

Does someone have a better or more simple solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do with an edge detection shader like this one (though it would need an extra pass):
http://ar3f.in/goochShading.html

Comment: can you elaborate  please?

Comment: Basically you render the scene into a render target texture. Then use that as an input to a second pass where you use a fragment shader to detect areas where there is an edge and draw pixels there. There are many different algorithms you can use ranging from very simple (just use a derivative function on the input image, and draw pixels where it is above a certain threshold), to more complicated. The example above uses Canny Edge Detection (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)

Comment: By downscaling the image you can achieve larger lines around the edges (as each pixel in the downscaled image    covers several pixels in the original image)